# Read csv file without headers and store each column into different sql table

Tags: python, sql, pandas, csv, load

I have csv file without headers and each column has different number of rows, like first column as H and second as D 3rd as G. I want to read the csv and store H in one table and D in other table and F in third table Using PYTHON Visual code. File is like this--

```
H|22|erewr|2.1|Asdsds|ASMINB|2.1||385904|Filename.TXT||20254545203|TEST|weerer-ertret-ret|FEE

D|MR|2343444|23296d26-a826-409d-bfd3-55ae09e0178f||UHC|423434fssdf|385904-10002465-01|1804874425|P|124|||||5555645961|176703||DEFAULT|99|||||||||||||565465||||||||||||||11||P||34ryyr4|6rrtytr||||^

F|MR|1670111520|234324-reert433-3334||ADC|erwerewr|
```

Comment: Why your separator is '|' ? You considered to first line as a "column" ? I'd say that the first column is `['H', 'D', 'F']`

Comment: Yes first column is ['H', 'D', 'F'] and each column has different number of rows. and each column starting with ['H', 'D', 'F'] has to load to three different sql tables with their respective rows

Answer (score 0):

So the process itself is relatively simple.

1. Open the file.
2. Iterate over the lines.
3. Get the first element in the line.
4. Based on the value, append to a list.

**EXAMPLE**

```py
splitchar = "|"
table_h = []
table_d = []
table_f = []

with open("somefile.csv") as infile:
    # the method below is OS agnostic, and removes the EOL character.
    for line in infile.read().splitlines():
        table = line.split(splitchar)[0]
        values_to_write = line.split(splitchar)[1:]
        if table == "H":
            table_h.append(values_to_write)
        elif table == "D":
            table_d.append(values_to_write)
        elif table == "F":
            table_f.append(values_to_write)
        # continue with elif selections here if needed

        else:
            #always nice to have a catchall
            print(f"Did not find a table to write to.\n  Table name == {table}\n  Values: {values_to_write}")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I m trying to access the file from nas drive and it should iterate for the files in that folder also and store in SQL tables wrt the first letters in csv file.

Comment: well the obvious thing would be to put that in your question. You're going to get the answer to the question you actually ask, as we cannot read your mind...